# Do setResumeCheckpoint commits revert after RetryableException?

Tags: apex, trigger, platform-event

I'm trying to build a high-volume integration through platform events, and I'd like to know how setResumeCheckpoint behaves when a RetryableException is thrown after the checkpoint.

According to the docs, setResumeCheckpoint starts processing events with a replay id after the last checkpoint, whereas RetryableException re-processes all events in the original trigger context (plus more). My question then is, does RetryableException reprocess only the events after the last checkpoint, or does it revert everything that has been done in a trigger.

Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_compare_checkpoint_retryable.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I performed the following test, and found that **RetryableException reverts everything committed through setResumeCheckpoint**:

```
// Test partial commit, then error.
trigger testevent on Test_Event__e (after insert) {
    System.debug('testevent [start]: Partial Commit Test');
    System.debug('testevent [size]: ' + Trigger.new.size());
    EventBus.TriggerContext tx = EventBus.TriggerContext.currentContext();
    tx.setResumeCheckpoint(Trigger.new[0].ReplayId);
    if (Trigger.new.size() > 1) throw new EventBus.RetryableException('Testing how retrying after a commit works.');
    System.debug('testevent [finished]');
}
```

When publishing two events at one time, this re-processes both events in subsequent instances of the trigger handler.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the way to fix it. You should add another setResumeCheckpoint in the end of your method after try catch for example with replayId of the last element. Then if you will have unhandled exception like LIMIT exception it will restart your events starting from saved + 1, otherwise it will stop restarting your events firing.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I have a couple questions on this:

1. Have you proven out that uncaught exceptions cause the replay logic to run? When I was testing, I was only able to accomplish this with (specifically) RetryableException instances explicitly thrown by my code. CPU timeout exceptions did not trigger a replay.

2. The above test models the scenario you described, where setResumeCheckpoint is set with a replay id. The test showed that this was completely ignored when an uncaught RetryableException was thrown. Do you have sample code that shows different behavior?

Comment: Actually it works especially for Limits errors. You just should know that new trigger will starts from the next element after checkpoint. To retry trigger from resume checkpoint this checkpoint should be set before exception.

Comment: That would be great -- Do you have sample code that shows different behavior than what I found?

Comment: Actually it is almost the same except I added try catch between two setResumeCheckpoint. The last one is like save progress and set that it is the end, to prevent restarting trigger. Here is the sample with description https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_batch_resume.htm

Comment: So in my realization at first I add setRezumeCheckpoint with 0 element, in the end with the last one

Comment: Hey, so there are a couple issues with this. First of all, limit exceptions physically cannot be caught, which is why I was looking for sample code in the event you ran across some workaround. But if you're using try/catch, then I doubt your code will work in handling limit errors.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000929cIAA

Comment: Second issue is, the question was around how a specific type of exception, RetryableException, interplays with setResumeCheckpoint. The entire point of RetryableException is to not be caught, and rather to trigger a retry through a different mechanism than setResumeCheckpoint. My findings were that it ignores setResumeCheckpoint when an uncaught RetryableException is thrown, and rather the entire collection of events is republished, just with a different "EventBus.TriggerContext.retries" counter value.

Comment: Your design pattern is one I often use, but it doesn't handle limits or address the question here, as far as I can tell. Feel free to provide sample code however if you think I've misunderstood. Thanks!

Comment: Actually as far as I tested setResumeCheckpoint if it was done before Limits exceptions  it resumes trigger since checkpoint. Try catch block need to handle handled exception not to reuse code with same exceptions (for what it should try to do the same that return an handled exception)

Comment: // Actually as far as I tested setResumeCheckpoint if it was done before Limits exceptions it resumes trigger since checkpoint. // Sounds reasonable; that's a good find, thanks. Concerning this answer and the various discussion points in the comments, it doesn't relate to the original question, so I'm leaving my answer as the accepted one for now. Thanks!